# Need libraries and code for LED dotmatrix driven by MAX7219

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt on Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm going to connect 8X8 LED dotmatrix driven by MAX7219.

I need libraries and code for that.

Answer (score -1):

if you know how to use Google, it's as simple as that.
There's tons of tutorials online.

greets,

Thomas

Comment: This is not a constructive answer as it stands, and would have served better as a comment, although admittedly, you lack the reputation to comment.

Comment: -_- frist of all I google every thing befor asking  ,I found things for arduino in c ... however I've found nothing in c++ for Rpi espacialy librarys  .... thx for your passing